# How to import Linux user to GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

Our project has many users using git repositories.

These users access git repositories with TortoiseGit by ssh://xxxx@reponame.

Now I am preparing GitLab and put my repositories to /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/reporitories/root, and then imported them into GitLab by following command.

```
# gitlab-rake gitlab:import:repos
```

It seems fine if I logged in GitLab.

Now how can I import /home/xxx users to GitLab?

It seems that GitLab manages users with LDAP, are there any useful functions in GitLab or LDAP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitlab offers multiple authentication methods. Gitlab can manage the user accounts itself or can use external services such as LDAP. For a full list and how to configure it, please take a look on [GitLab Integration documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/integration/README.html).

GitLab offers an API which can be used to automatically add new users. You need to create a script for that, but its worth if you have dozens of users. There is actually a python module [pyapi-gitlab](http://pyapi-gitlab.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for this API. I also stumbled on a quick search over a tool called [python-gitlab](http://fedir.github.io/web/2014/01/06/gitlab-projects-management-from-shell/) I haven't heard about before. Might be worth a try.

[This documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/raketasks/user_management.html) might be helpful when it comes to adding *existing* users to already available groups